# Why does VBA script stuck on End Sub statement

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA script that uses a relatively large number of variables that store calculation data on an Excel sheet, including a big size of arrays.

The script is reached the `End Sub` statement very quickly (~ 5 sec), but the `End Sub` statement causes Excel to freeze and not respond for a long period (~ 45 Minutes).

I have tried several suggested solutions from the internet without success.

I put a breakpoint on the `End Sub` statement and it reached, but step over caused Excel to not respond for a lot of time.

The relevant subroutine:

```vb
Sub PriorityCalculate()
   Worksheets("SIM").Select
   
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   
   Dim AllProductsByProirity() As Integer, ProductsDueDates() As Date
   Dim rng As Range, column As Range, cell As Range
   Dim column_number As Integer, num_of_products As Integer, minimum_row_index As Integer, maximum_row_index As Integer
   Dim product_name_row_index As Integer, product_count_row_index As Integer, priority_row_index As Integer
   Dim date_row_index As Integer
   Dim due_date_row_index As Integer
   Dim part_number_column As Integer, description_column As Integer
   Dim sim_analyzer_sheet_name As String, no_order_sheet_name As String
   Dim startIndexOfProduct As Integer, stockShortIndex As Integer
   startIndexOfProduct = 2
   stockShortIndex = 1
   
   sim_analyzer_sheet_name = "SIM Analyzer"
   no_order_sheet_name = "No Order"
   
   minimum_row_index = Cells.Find("Part number").row + 1
   priority_row_index = Cells.Find("Paririty").row
   product_count_row_index = Cells.Find("SIM qty").row
   date_row_index = Cells.Find("Product convergence date").row
   due_date_row_index = Cells.Find("Target date").row
   part_number_column = Cells.Find("Part number").column
   description_column = Cells.Find("des").column
   product_name_row_index = Cells.Find("Part number").row
   maximum_row_index = 10000
   
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Exit For
    End If
   Next i
   
   maximum_row_index = i - 1
   
   Set rng = Range("EH5:PU5")
   num_of_products = rng.Columns.Count
   ReDim AllProductsByProirity(1 To num_of_products + stockShortIndex)
   ReDim ProductsDueDates(1 To num_of_products + stockShortIndex)
   
   ProductsDueDates(stockShortIndex) = Date
   For Each column In rng.Columns
    Set cell = Cells(priority_row_index, column.column)
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    AllProductsByProirity(cell.Value + stockShortIndex) = column.column
    If IsEmpty(Cells(due_date_row_index, column.column).Value) Then
        ProductsDueDates(cell.Value + stockShortIndex) = CDate(0)
    Else
        ProductsDueDates(cell.Value + stockShortIndex) = Cells(due_date_row_index, column.column).Value
    End If
   Next column
   
   Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
   Dim SumAll() As Double
   ReDim SumAll(1 To num_of_products + stockShortIndex, minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index)
   
   For i = startIndexOfProduct To num_of_products + stockShortIndex
    column_number = AllProductsByProirity(i)
    If column_number = 0 Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For k = minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index
        If IsNumeric(Cells(k, column_number)) Then
            SumAll(i, k) = Cells(k, column_number).Value * Cells(product_count_row_index, column_number).Value
        Else
            SumAll(i, k) = 0
        End If
    Next k
        
    Dim addedRows() As Boolean
    Erase addedRows
    ReDim addedRows(minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index)

   Next i
   
   Dim sum As Double
   Dim stock_range As Range, order_count_range As Range, order_date_range As Range
   Dim current_stock_column As Integer, stock_column As Integer, order_count_column As Integer, order_date_column As Integer
   
   current_stock_column = Cells.Find("Available inventory after paki").column
   
   Dim AllDates() As Variant
   ReDim AllDates(1 To num_of_products + stockShortIndex, minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index)
   
   Dim max_num_of_orders As Integer, current_num_of_orders As Integer
   max_num_of_orders = 100
   current_num_of_orders = 0
   num_of_stocks = 0
   Dim orders_stock_columns() As Integer, orders_number_columns() As Integer, orders_count_columns() As Integer, orders_date_columns() As Integer
   Dim orders_shipping_days_columns() As Integer, orders_supply_columns() As Integer, orders_supplier_number_columns() As Integer, orders_manufacturer_columns() As Integer, _
   orders_manufacturer_part_number_columns() As Integer
   Dim orders_supplier_name_columns() As Integer
   ReDim orders_stock_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_count_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_date_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_shipping_days_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_number_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_supplier_name_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_supply_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_supplier_number_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_manufacturer_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   ReDim orders_manufacturer_part_number_columns(1 To max_num_of_orders)
   
   For stock_id = 1 To max_num_of_orders
        Set stock_range = Cells.Find("stk rep " & stock_id)
        If stock_range Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
        num_of_stocks = stock_id
        orders_stock_columns(num_of_stocks) = stock_range.column
   Next stock_id
   
   For order_id = 1 To max_num_of_orders
        Set order_number_range = Cells.Find("order " & order_id)
        If order_number_range Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
        current_num_of_orders = order_id
        orders_number_columns(current_num_of_orders) = order_number_range.column
        orders_supplier_name_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("supplier " & order_id).column
        orders_date_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("date " & order_id).column
        orders_count_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("balance " & order_id).column
        orders_shipping_days_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("shipping days " & order_id).column
        
        orders_supply_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("Supply Number " & order_id).column
        orders_supplier_number_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("Supplier Number " & order_id).column
        orders_manufacturer_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("MFG " & order_id).column
        orders_manufacturer_part_number_columns(current_num_of_orders) = Cells.Find("MFG PN " & order_id).column
   Next order_id
   
   Dim ordersAfterDueDates() As New ExpediteOrder
   ReDim ordersAfterDueDates(1 To num_of_products + stockShortIndex, minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index, 1 To current_num_of_orders)
   
   Set productItemsWithoutOrder = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
   Set notEmptyOrders = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
   
   Dim order As ExpediteOrder
   Dim ProductItemWithoutOrder As ProductItemWithoutOrder
   Dim orderUpdatedCount() As Double
   ReDim orderUpdatedCount(minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index, 1 To current_num_of_orders)
   Dim stocks() As Double
   ReDim stocks(minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index)
   Dim ORDER_IS_EMPTY As Double, NO_STOCK As Double
   ORDER_IS_EMPTY = -0.1
   NO_STOCK = -0.1
   
   For i = startIndexOfProduct To num_of_products + stockShortIndex
    For k = minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index
        Dim stock As Double
        stock = stocks(k)
        sum = SumAll(i, k)
        
        If stock = 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(Cells(k, current_stock_column).Value) Then
                stock = stock + Cells(k, current_stock_column).Value
            End If
            
            For stock_id = 1 To num_of_stocks
                stock_column = orders_stock_columns(stock_id)
                If IsNumeric(Cells(k, stock_column).Value) Then
                    stock = stock + Cells(k, stock_column).Value
                End If
            Next stock_id
            stocks(k) = stock
        End If
        
        If stock = NO_STOCK Then
            stock = 0
        End If
        
        If stock < 0 Then
            'Insert stock as current short
            Call AddOrders(False, stock, product_name_row_index, stockShortIndex, k, current_num_of_orders, part_number_column, description_column, AllProductsByProirity, _
                            orders_count_columns, orders_date_columns, orders_shipping_days_columns, orders_number_columns, orders_supplier_name_columns, _
                            orders_supply_columns, orders_supplier_number_columns, orders_manufacturer_columns, orders_manufacturer_part_number_columns, orderUpdatedCount, ProductsDueDates, SumAll, _
                            ordersAfterDueDates, productItemsWithoutOrder, AllDates)
            stock = 0
            stocks(k) = NO_STOCK
        End If
        
        If sum <> 0 Then
            sum = stock - sum
        End If
        
        If sum >= 0 Then
            AllDates(i, k) = CDate(0)
            If sum = 0 And SumAll(i, k) <> 0 Then
                stocks(k) = NO_STOCK
            ElseIf sum > 0 Then
                stocks(k) = sum
            End If
        Else
            stocks(k) = NO_STOCK
            Call AddOrders(True, sum, product_name_row_index, i, k, current_num_of_orders, part_number_column, description_column, AllProductsByProirity, _
                orders_count_columns, orders_date_columns, orders_shipping_days_columns, orders_number_columns, orders_supplier_name_columns, _
                orders_supply_columns, orders_supplier_number_columns, orders_manufacturer_columns, orders_manufacturer_part_number_columns, _
                orderUpdatedCount, ProductsDueDates, SumAll, ordersAfterDueDates, productItemsWithoutOrder, AllDates)
        End If
    Next k
   Next i
   
   Dim dates() As Date
   ReDim dates(minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index)
   Dim MaxDate As Date
   Dim IsNoOrder As Boolean
   Dim order_number_column As Integer
   
   For i = startIndexOfProduct To num_of_products + stockShortIndex
    Erase dates
    ReDim dates(minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index)
    IsNoOrder = False
    For k = minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index
        If IsDate(AllDates(i, k)) Then
            dates(k) = AllDates(i, k)
        Else
            IsNoOrder = True
            dates(k) = CDate(0)
        End If
    Next k
    
    MaxDate = CDate(0)
    For k = minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index
        If dates(k) > MaxDate Then
            MaxDate = dates(k)
        End If
    Next k
        
    Cells(date_row_index, AllProductsByProirity(i)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    If MaxDate <> CDate(0) Then
        Cells(date_row_index, AllProductsByProirity(i)).Value = MaxDate
    Else
        Cells(date_row_index, AllProductsByProirity(i)).Value = ""
    End If
    
    If IsNoOrder Then
        Cells(date_row_index - 1, AllProductsByProirity(i)).Value = "No Order"
    Else
        If MaxDate = CDate(0) Then
            Cells(date_row_index - 1, AllProductsByProirity(i)).Value = "Good"
        Else
            Cells(date_row_index - 1, AllProductsByProirity(i)).Value = ""
        End If
    End If
   Next i
      
   With Sheets(sim_analyzer_sheet_name)
    Dim start_of_data_row As Integer
    Dim delivery_date_column As Integer, supplier_name_column As Integer
    Dim quantity_column As Integer, quantity_to_expedite_column As Integer, request_expedite_date_column As Integer, product_name_column As Integer
    Dim supplier_number_column As Integer, supply_number_column As Integer, manufacturer_column As Integer, manufacturer_part_number_column As Integer
    Dim shipping_days_column As Integer, product_quantity_needed_column As Integer
    
    part_number_column = .Cells.Find("Part number").column
    description_column = .Cells.Find("Description").column
    supplier_number_column = .Cells.Find("Supplier Number").column
    supplier_name_column = .Cells.Find("Supplier Name").column
    order_number_column = .Cells.Find("Order Number").column
    supply_number_column = .Cells.Find("Supply Number").column
    manufacturer_column = .Cells.Find("Manufacturer").column
    manufacturer_part_number_column = .Cells.Find("Manufacturer P/N").column
    delivery_date_column = .Cells.Find("Delivery date").column
    shipping_days_column = .Cells.Find("Shipping days").column
    quantity_column = .Cells.Find("Quantity").column
    request_expedite_date_column = .Cells.Find("Request expedite date").column
    quantity_to_expedite_column = .Cells.Find("Quantity to expedite").column
    product_name_column = .Cells.Find("Product").column
    product_quantity_needed_column = .Cells.Find("Product quantity needed").column
    start_of_data_row = .Cells.Find("Part number").row + 1
    
    .Rows(start_of_data_row & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
        
    Dim MaxOrder As ExpediteOrder
    Dim current_order As ExpediteOrder
    For i = stockShortIndex To num_of_products + stockShortIndex
        Set MaxOrder = New ExpediteOrder
        due_date = ProductsDueDates(i)
        If due_date = CDate(0) Then
            Set MaxOrder = GetMaximumOrderDeliveryDate(ordersAfterDueDates, i, minimum_row_index, maximum_row_index, current_num_of_orders)
            If MaxOrder.DeliveryDate <> CDate(0) Then
                Call WriteOrder(sim_analyzer_sheet_name, MaxOrder, start_of_data_row, part_number_column, description_column, supplier_number_column, supplier_name_column, _
                                order_number_column, supply_number_column, manufacturer_column, manufacturer_part_number_column, delivery_date_column, shipping_days_column, _
                                quantity_column, request_expedite_date_column, quantity_to_expedite_column, product_name_column, product_quantity_needed_column)
            
                start_of_data_row = start_of_data_row + 1
            End If
        Else
            For k = minimum_row_index To maximum_row_index
               For order_id = 1 To current_num_of_orders
                    Set current_order = ordersAfterDueDates(i, k, order_id)
                    If current_order.OrderNumber <> 0 Then
                        notEmptyOrders.Add current_order
                    End If
                Next order_id
            Next k
        End If
    Next i
    
    If notEmptyOrders.Count = 0 Then
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        GoTo WriteNoOrderSheet
    End If
    
    Dim partNumberDict As New Dictionary
    Dim descriptionDict As New Dictionary
    Dim supplierNumberDict As New Dictionary
    Dim supplierDict As New Dictionary
    Dim orderNumberDict As New Dictionary
    Dim supplyDict As New Dictionary
    Dim manufacturerDict As New Dictionary
    Dim manufacturerPartNumberDict As New Dictionary
    Dim DeliveryDates() As Date
    ReDim DeliveryDates(notEmptyOrders.Count, 1)
    Dim shippingDaysDict As New Dictionary
    Dim quantityDict As New Dictionary
    Dim RequestExpediteDates() As Date
    ReDim RequestExpediteDates(notEmptyOrders.Count, 1)
    Dim quantityToExpediteDict As New Dictionary
    Dim productNameDict As New Dictionary
    Dim productQuantityNeededDict As New Dictionary
    
    i = 0
    For Each order In notEmptyOrders
        partNumberDict.Add i, order.PartNumber
        descriptionDict.Add i, order.Description
        supplierNumberDict.Add i, order.supplierNum
        supplierDict.Add i, order.Supplier
        orderNumberDict.Add i, order.OrderNumber
        supplyDict.Add i, order.supply
        manufacturerDict.Add i, order.manufacturer
        manufacturerPartNumberDict.Add i, order.manufacturerPartNumber
        DeliveryDates(i, 0) = order.DeliveryDate
        shippingDaysDict.Add i, order.shippingDays
        quantityDict.Add i, order.Quantity
        If order.RequestExpediteDate <> CDate(0) Then
            RequestExpediteDates(i, 0) = CDate(order.RequestExpediteDate)
        Else
            RequestExpediteDates(i, 0) = ""
        End If
        quantityToExpediteDict.Add i, order.QuantityToExpedite
        productNameDict.Add i, order.productName
        productQuantityNeededDict.Add i, order.productQuantityNeeded
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    Dim part_number_column_name As String, description_column_name As String, supplier_number_column_name As String, supplier_name_column_name As String, _
    order_number_column_name As String, supply_column_name As String, manufacturer_column_name As String, manufacturer_part_number_column_name As String, _
    delivery_date_column_name As String, shipping_days_column_name As String, quantity_column_name As String, request_expedite_date_column_name As String, _
    product_name_column_name As String, product_quantity_needed_column_name As String
        
    part_number_column_name = Split(.Cells(, part_number_column).Address, "$")(1)
    description_column_name = Split(.Cells(, description_column).Address, "$")(1)
    supplier_number_column_name = Split(.Cells(, supplier_number_column).Address, "$")(1)
    supplier_name_column_name = Split(.Cells(, supplier_name_column).Address, "$")(1)
    order_number_column_name = Split(.Cells(, order_number_column).Address, "$")(1)
    supply_column_name = Split(.Cells(, supply_number_column).Address, "$")(1)
    manufacturer_column_name = Split(.Cells(, manufacturer_column).Address, "$")(1)
    manufacturer_part_number_column_name = Split(.Cells(, manufacturer_part_number_column).Address, "$")(1)
    delivery_date_column_name = Split(.Cells(, delivery_date_column).Address, "$")(1)
    shipping_days_column_name = Split(.Cells(, shipping_days_column).Address, "$")(1)
    quantity_column_name = Split(.Cells(, quantity_column).Address, "$")(1)
    quantity_to_expedite_column_name = Split(.Cells(, quantity_to_expedite_column).Address, "$")(1)
    request_expedite_date_column_name = Split(.Cells(, request_expedite_date_column).Address, "$")(1)
    product_name_column_name = Split(.Cells(, product_name_column).Address, "$")(1)
    product_quantity_needed_column_name = Split(.Cells(, product_quantity_needed_column).Address, "$")(1)
    
    .Range(part_number_column_name & start_of_data_row, part_number_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(partNumberDict.Items)
    .Range(description_column_name & start_of_data_row, description_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(descriptionDict.Items)
    .Range(supplier_number_column_name & start_of_data_row, supplier_number_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(supplierNumberDict.Items)
    .Range(supplier_name_column_name & start_of_data_row, supplier_name_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(supplierDict.Items)
    .Range(order_number_column_name & start_of_data_row, order_number_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(orderNumberDict.Items)
    
    .Range(supply_column_name & start_of_data_row, supply_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(supplyDict.Items)
    .Range(manufacturer_column_name & start_of_data_row, manufacturer_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(manufacturerDict.Items)
    .Range(manufacturer_part_number_column_name & start_of_data_row, manufacturer_part_number_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(manufacturerPartNumberDict.Items)
    .Range(delivery_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, delivery_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Range(delivery_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, delivery_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Range(delivery_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, delivery_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = DeliveryDates
    .Range(shipping_days_column_name & start_of_data_row, shipping_days_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(shippingDaysDict.Items)
    .Range(quantity_column_name & start_of_data_row, quantity_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(quantityDict.Items)
    .Range(request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Range(request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Range(request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = RequestExpediteDates
    .Range(quantity_to_expedite_column_name & start_of_data_row, quantity_to_expedite_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(quantityToExpediteDict.Items)
    .Range(product_name_column_name & start_of_data_row, product_name_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(productNameDict.Items)
    .Range(product_quantity_needed_column_name & start_of_data_row, product_quantity_needed_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(productQuantityNeededDict.Items)
    
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
   
   
WriteNoOrderSheet:
   With Sheets(no_order_sheet_name)
    partNumberDict.RemoveAll
    descriptionDict.RemoveAll
    Erase RequestExpediteDates
    ReDim RequestExpediteDates(productItemsWithoutOrder.Count, 1)
    quantityToExpediteDict.RemoveAll
    productNameDict.RemoveAll
    productQuantityNeededDict.RemoveAll
    
    If productItemsWithoutOrder.Count = 0 Then
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    i = 0
    For Each productItem In productItemsWithoutOrder
        partNumberDict.Add i, productItem.PartNumber
        descriptionDict.Add i, productItem.Description
        If productItem.RequestExpediteDate <> CDate(0) Then
            RequestExpediteDates(i, 0) = CDate(productItem.RequestExpediteDate)
        Else
            RequestExpediteDates(i, 0) = ""
        End If
        quantityToExpediteDict.Add i, productItem.QuantityToExpedite
        productNameDict.Add i, productItem.productName
        productQuantityNeededDict.Add i, productItem.productQuantityNeeded
        i = i + 1
    Next
           
    part_number_column = .Cells.Find("Part number").column
    description_column = .Cells.Find("Description").column
    request_expedite_date_column = .Cells.Find("Request expedite date").column
    quantity_to_expedite_column = .Cells.Find("Quantity to expedite").column
    product_name_column = .Cells.Find("Product").column
    product_quantity_needed_column = .Cells.Find("Product quantity needed").column
    start_of_data_row = .Cells.Find("Part number").row + 1
    
    .Rows(start_of_data_row & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
        
    part_number_column_name = Split(.Cells(, part_number_column).Address, "$")(1)
    description_column_name = Split(.Cells(, description_column).Address, "$")(1)
    quantity_to_expedite_column_name = Split(.Cells(, quantity_to_expedite_column).Address, "$")(1)
    request_expedite_date_column_name = Split(.Cells(, request_expedite_date_column).Address, "$")(1)
    product_name_column_name = Split(.Cells(, product_name_column).Address, "$")(1)
    product_quantity_needed_column_name = Split(.Cells(, product_quantity_needed_column).Address, "$")(1)
    
    .Range(part_number_column_name & start_of_data_row, part_number_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(partNumberDict.Items)
    .Range(description_column_name & start_of_data_row, description_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(descriptionDict.Items)
    .Range(request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Range(request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Range(request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row, request_expedite_date_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = RequestExpediteDates
    .Range(quantity_to_expedite_column_name & start_of_data_row, quantity_to_expedite_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(quantityToExpediteDict.Items)
    .Range(product_name_column_name & start_of_data_row, product_name_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(productNameDict.Items)
    .Range(product_quantity_needed_column_name & start_of_data_row, product_quantity_needed_column_name & start_of_data_row + i - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(productQuantityNeededDict.Items)
    
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
   
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I spent a lot of time on this issue, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What kind of things do you instantiate there? `End Sub` is where it will all get cleaned. Do you have high CPU usage at that point? Memory? Hitting the page file really hard? Are you sure `End Sub` is reached in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I am sure `End Sub` is reached, I put breakpoint one line before, and the breakpoint is reached. I had High Memory usage at that point.

Comment: If you're filling the sheet with a lot of formulas then you might expect that turning calculation back on would cause a delay.  45mins is a lot of calculation time but not impossible to reach...  Would be useful to say more about exactly what your code does, and some idea of the scale of your data.

Comment: I am not filling the sheet with formulas. My script is doing the all calculations and writing the results to another sheet.

Comment: Looks like you've reached a standstill. Maybe it's about time to post the complete (relevant) code. Also, if the line before `End Sub` is something like `Next i`, then it is expected for the code to run somewhat longer. You should put the breakpoint on the `End Sub` line and see what is happening.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the `End Sub` and it reached but one step over caused Excel to not respond for a lot of time. I posted the relevant code.

Comment: You weren't lying when you said it was long. It looks like it's impossible (it isn't) to find what is wrong with it. You need to seriously consider refactoring this into many procedures e.g. instead of the many variables you should use data structures. Note that data structures can also hold other data structures. It will be quite a challenge. You previously put a breakpoint on the `Application.EnableEvents = True` line, so one could conclude that you have some (maybe only one) event codes that are poorly written and are causing 'too many' recalculations. Check those first. Use `Timer`.

Comment: I have no event codes...

Comment: Any other suggestions?